# How to display the value a user puts into an "input="date"" box and clicks submit button using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am very new to Javascript and I have what I believe to be a simple problem -

I have an area on a main page that I want to use javascript to populate with the date that a user inputs into an "input="date"" field on one page. Basically the user clicks to this page, puts in a date and hits a "submit" button, and on the main page, the dedicated area grabs that value and displays it.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Thus far this is what I have:

```
<div data-role="content">   
        Content
                <input id="date" type="date" name="airdate">
                <input name="buttonExecute" onclick="execute(document.getElementById('date').value);" type="button" value="Execute" />

                <script>
var text = document.getElementById('date').value;
</script>

    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide some code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I left that out...

Comment: Could you also show your execute function?

Comment: This will show how green I am to Java - this is all I have, cobbled together from online research. Horrible I know - I tried something using a variable and a prompt, and then using console.log to display it, but it won't display.

I have that var text = document... in where I want it to pull the code from the submitted date - if that's the execute part?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so if I understood you correctly, this is what you want:

```
<div id='display'></div>
<div data-role="content">   
    Content
    <input id="date" type="date" name="airdate">
    <input name="buttonExecute" onclick="execute(document.getElementById('date').value);" type="button" value="Execute" />
    <script>
        function execute (e) {
            var e2 = document.getElementById('display');
            e2.innerHTML = e;
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/37gUR/1